# Delete a file inside subfolder using bat

Tags: search, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I know the name of the subfolder inside which the file I want to delete is located. The name of the subfolder is "My Subfolder" and the file I want to delete inside the subfolder is "The-Bad File.txt" . I am at "D" drive. "My Subfolder" is located inside "Folder-2" "Folder-4" "Folder-54" and "Folder-543". I want to search these folders only to delete "Bad File.txt" using .bat file inside "My Subfolder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't always now exactly all locations where "My Subfolder" exists, and you want to delete the file from all such locations.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s "d:\My Subfolder"') do del "%%F\The-Bad File.txt"
```

To delete the file from all folders beneath "My Subfolder", all you need to do is add the `/S` option to the DEL command.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s "d:\My Subfolder"') do del /s "%%F\The-Bad File.txt"
```

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. Please do a bit more? The "Bad File.txt" is not inside `D:\Folder-x\My Subfolder\` in all the cases. Its can be in `D:\Folder-x\My Subfolder\xxxx\"` or may be in `D:\Folder-x\My Subfolder\xxxx\yyyyy\"` whatever the case is, "Bad File.txt" should be deleted. Please help; this answer is toooooo close..

Comment: Ya, I have already done that. Now its saying 'access denied'. Running as administrator still access denied.

Comment: @Deb - ??? Did you place the command in a batch script? If not, then you need to change all `%%` into `%` when run from the command prompt. The access denied message may arise if it attempts to access other user folders that exist on the machine. You could try to add `2>nul` to the DIR command to suppress the error message. I'm not sure how get access to folders you don't have access to. That might be a good question for SuperUser.

Comment: Actually I am compiling the bat into exe. Then running it as administrator. Your answer really helped and will look forward for further help regarding bat scripting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This will delete "Bad File.txt" in every place it is found below the current folder.

```
@echo off
del /s "Bad File.txt"
```

Comment: This will delete the file from ***all*** folders. The OP only wants to delete from folders named "My Subfolder"

Comment: set curent directory to "My Subfolder" and then call del /s "Bad File.txt".

Comment: @mihai_mandis   "My Subfolder" is located **inside** "Folder-2" "Folder-4" "Folder-54" and "Folder-543".

Comment: cd "Folder-2\Folder-4\Folder-54\Folder-543\My Subfolder"

Comment: I actually do not no the parent folder of "My Subfolder". And if I do what you suggest, it will then search the entire drive for "Bad File.txt" . It will take a lot of time.

Comment: @dbenham The OP said `using .bat file inside "My Subfolder".` so it's only going to delete the ones as I said.

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in (2 4 54 543) do echo del "D:\Folder-%%a\My Subfolder\The-Bad File.txt"
```

Remove `echo` if it should work.

€dit:
If the start folder of the batch is located in one of the "My Subfolder" folders, this should work:

```
 for /d %%a in (..\*) do echo del "%%~a\My Subfolder\The-Bad File.txt"
```

Comment: +1, Yes, a very literal interpretation of question. I assumed the OP did not necessarily know all locations of the "My Subfolder" - but upon further review, I realize the question doesn't actually say that.

Comment: See , I do not know the parent folder of "My Subfolder" . Folder-2, Folder-4 etc are arbitrary examples.

Comment: The way I asked, was not right. So, any better edit is welcome. @dbenham in his answer has given the the solution of my problem. Thanks for other replies.

Comment: @Endoro This is helpful too.